# Take values from one db into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an sql query that will do the following.

I have two databases, one is databaseA and the other is databaseB.

They both have similar tables called zone.

Both tables called zone have different amounts of columns,  but some columns are the same.The only columns im concerned with for now are ID and minclip.

I need a query that will take the value of databaseA's zone min_clip and insert it into each row in databaseB's zone minclip, but only when the ID value of both databases match.

So it would take the minclip value from databaseA.zone and insert it into databaseB.zone where the id column of both match.

Comment: Do you have primary key on ID field?

Comment: Yes there is a primary key on ID field

Comment: Do you think people come here and ask questions who *don't* need assistance? Or that you're somehow more worthy of help than anyone else asking a question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, basically you want to UPDATE values in `databaseB.zone` from `databaseA.zone`, not insert:

```
update databaseB.zone 
set minclip=(select databaseA.zone.minclip 
from databaseA.zone where databaseA.zone.ID=databaseB.zone.ID)
```

Given your problem with data being truncated, let's try generating SQL statements from values in `databaseA.zone`:

```
select concat('update databaseB.zone 
    set minclip=',minclip,' where ID=',ID,';') from databaseA.zone
```

Take an output of this SQL and run it.

There will be bunch of zero record updates, but I won't start intersecting `databaseA.zone` and `databaseB.zone` to keep it simple.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, and i got several warnings of

Data truncated for column 'minclip' at row 376,  and all the values of 'minclip'were set to 0. (dont worry, have several backups)

the column types are the same type (FLOAT) on both so I dont understand what the problem could be

Comment: What warnings, in particular?

Comment: sorry,  accidentally added comment before I was finished typing

Comment: Aha, so here we are presented with a problem of having `minclip` in those tables of different types. Post your structures here, I think you have `int` in target table and `varchar` in source.

Comment: Oh. You edited your comment. So you say they are of the same type. Can you post several records?

Comment: I'm sorry, whats an sql query to get something that i can post? (im using heidisql)

Comment: IT's something like `select ID,minclip from zone where ID>=0 and ID<10`. Change `0` and `10` to get approximately 10 records and run this on both tables.

Comment: I dont know how to post this, but I can assure you that they records were exactly the same,  I am beginning to think I should just manually enter the data

Comment: Wait. When something acts weird, there is always a workaround. I'll post an update to answer in a minute.

Comment: That looks like its on the right track, how can I just use those results to produce a sql query?

Comment: I get things like update databaseB.zone 
    set minclip=200 where ID=1;

update databaseB.zone 
    set minclip=100 where ID=2;

etc

Comment: I could manually copy and paste each of these results as its own query to get the job done,  but is there a way just to have all the results in one long .sql file or query?

Comment: Yes, this is what you should get. Redirect output to file and run this file.